# Can we input the git command output to another git command

Tags: git

My requirement is to fetch the list of folders, which got some modifications of the files after certain date.

I tried and got below commands from which I can get some details:

This command lists the commits which are done after this date (`2016-05-26`):

```
git log --date=short --after=2016-05-26 --pretty=format:"%h"
```

Output:

```
5761f52
7c589b8
1ee709d
```

This command lists the filename that is changed on this commit (`5761f52`):

```
git show --pretty="format:" --name-only 5761f52
```

Output:

```
Dummy/Dummy_file.java
```

Instead of checking after each commit, is there any way to fetch the list for the group of commits?

Answer (score 0):

Mureinik answer seems to be good for me. But if you disagree, you can use a loop in bash command line

```
for commit in `git log --date=short --after=2016-05-26 --pretty=format:"%h"` 
do 
echo "====== Commit $commit is beeing analyzed ======";
git show --pretty="format:" --name-only $commit;
done
```

Comment: Thanks Flows your answer helped me. Also I slightly modified the Mureinik answer `git log --pretty="format:" --name-only --after=2016-05-24` it also worked.

Comment: Could you please accept my answer if it works for you ? Or add a comment if you need more helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass `--name-only` to `git diff`. Assuming your ref log goes back far enough, you can just use:

```
git diff --name-only master@{2016-05-26}
```

Answer (score 0):

The command

```bash
git log --date=short --after=2016-05-26 --pretty=format:"%h" \
| xargs git show --pretty="format:" --name-only | grep -v '^$' | sort -u
```

will do exactly what you ask for - use the output from a git command as input to another via the [xargs program](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html).

The grep command is to filter out blank lines, and the `-u` option to sort is to get files changed multiple times to be listed only once.